# ps x shows weird command: -f html/index.php

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, web-server, cgi

Just went to check one of my websites and was greeted by the message: "CGIWrap Error: Real UID could not be changed!". Went in via SSH and tried "ps x" which showed me tons of processes that that where just "-f " and the path to index.php or some other php file. After killing all processes everything went back to normal.

Anyone know what that is? Google did not help at all.

Comment: I just checked and someone has been hammering my page trying to find sql injection exploits. Could it be that too many scripts timed out and I got this message as a result?